# Running jquery in IE9 in an xml file in Local Intranet Zone

Tags: local, internet-explorer-9, intranet

I have an xml file that renders a html using xslt. Nothing special here and it works in IE7 and IE8 just fine. However, in IE9 it does not render the jquery part of the file on "Local Intranet" zone

The file runs as http://localhost/xml/index.xml

1. Checked all the settings under custom in "Local Intranet" and all of them are enabled
2. Made sure that it runs on IE8 on the same browser using the developer tool.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and managed to get it to work in compatability mode.